# Error: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './assets/logo.png'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, eas

I built out an expo app and was able to get it working on Android and iOS when running it. However when I run "eas build --platform android" is when the error comes up. Building for iOS worked fine.

I also have this in my package.json: "icon": "./assets/logo.png"